# How to parse docx according to headings using OpenXml

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, docx

I have a Docx document with the following format:

[image: word template example]

I have these classes:

```
class Subject
{
    public Subject ParentSubject { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> ChildSubjects { get; set; }

    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public List<Question> GetAllQuestions()
    {
        var allQuestions = Questions.ToList();
        foreach (var item in ChildSubjects)
        {
            allQuestions.AddRange(item.GetAllQuestions());
        }
        return allQuestions;
    }
}

class Question
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public string Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

I created a parser and get all paragraphs:

```
public static List<Subject> ParseFromExcel(string file)
{
    List<Subject> result = new();
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
    {
        Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        var reg = new Regex(@"^[\s\p{L}\d\•\-\►]");
        foreach (Paragraph co in body.Descendants<Paragraph>())
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't know what would be the next steps. I tried to use the GetAttributes method of the paragraph but it couldn't help. So, If the text is referenced it is the subject, Answer starts with `Correct Answer:` text and the explanation starts with `Explanation:`. If subject is under another heading it means it is a child subject. So, how can I parse it?

Comment: Download Microsoft's OpenXML Productivity Tool (it's a bit hard to find, Microsoft has hidden it). It will allow you to reflect over your sample document and see how it's structured, both as XML and as C# code. You can often figure things out from there (that tool, by the way , is useful for just about any OpenXML efgort)

Comment: The question is asking the programming language and methods, not the structure of the document.  The question doesn't ask for you to write a parser.